# Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> ReferenceError: grunt is not defined

Tags: gruntjs

there is a problem in my code.

I wrote in concole: grunt connect

This is the errormessage:

Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > ReferenceError: grunt is not defined
> >     Warning: Task "connect" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

---

And this is my gruntfile.js file:

---

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 // Project configuration.
 grunt.initConfig({
   pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    connect: {
     uses_defaults: {}
   }

 });
 // Load Grunt plugins
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('');
 // Default task(s).
 grunt.registerTask('default', []);
};



// Load Grunt plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
```

---

What is the problem in my code?
Why doesn't it find the connect task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Every Gruntfile (and gruntplugin) uses this basic format, and all of your Grunt code must be specified inside this function:" -https://gruntjs.com/getting-started

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Do grunt-related things in here
};
```

Moving `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');` inside this function should fix it.

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed this :)
Thank you for the fast answer! :)